# how to dependency injection inversion of control design pattern ninject method class repository

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, ninject

How do I dependency injection this code:

```
public void someMethod() {
  using (AuthRepository _repo = new AuthRepository()) {
    // use _repo
  }
}
```

using ninject.

Answer (score 0):

By using constructor injection like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    private readonly IAuthRepository authRepository;

    public MyClass(IAuthRepository authRepository) {
        this.authRepository = authRepository;
    }

    public void someMethod() {
      // use _repo
    }
}
```

Comment: But `MyClass` is instantiated once, and I need to create `authRepository` each time `someMethod` is called.

Comment: One option is to inject a factory `IAuthRepositoryFactory` that can produce the `authRepository`, and use the factory in `someMethod` so you can create an instance each time the method is run.

Comment: Why is `MyClass` instantiated once? If that's the problem: don't do that; register it as transient.